# Firebase App Distribution How to update the app to a new version, without uninstall the current version

Tags: android, firebase, bitrise, firebase-app-distribution

I'm working on an Android development and I want the testers to update the app without uninstalling the current version of the app.
The situation is like, when developers make a pull request to a development branch, I want others to check a new feature on the device.

If the user has already installed the older version of the app and tried to install the new version from App Tester app, everytime they see the dialog saying "Do you want to uninstall the app?"
After they hit ok and uninstall the old version, the new version will be installed.

I want to remove the process for uninstalling the app, so when the user hits the download button in the second pic, the app is updated to the selected version without the uninstalling process.

How can I achieve that?
For distribution, I use [the Firebase app distribution step](https://devcenter.bitrise.io/en/steps-and-workflows/workflow-recipes-for-android-apps/-android--deploy-to-firebase-app-distribution.html) in bitrise.

I have tried changing both version code and version name, but it didn't work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know Bitrise.....who choose Keystore and its Alias Passwords? Bitrise do it for you? If yes: it could create a new keystore each time, so the signature changes at each release and Android will ask to Uninstall a prev existent package with the same name.